# cronjob not working on Debian

Tags: cron, debian

I don't know why my cronjob doesn't run the way I expect. I added the following line to `crontab -e`.

`* * * * * /home/cookiemon/test.sh`

This script is executable and simply appends current time to output.txt

```
#!/bin/sh
date >> output.txt
```

It seems that this script is running correctly when I check the log at `/var/log/syslog`. However, the output.txt file is never created. I tried this with `sudo crontab -e`, but the result was exactly the same. What am I doing wrong?

FYI, I am using Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the output.txt file is never created.

The script is producing the output at a location where you don't have write access.

Specify the complete path to the log.

```
#!/bin/sh
date >> /home/cookiemon/output.txt
```

Comment: That works! It's kind of obvious after seeing you answer... Thank a lot.